# hg / mercurial: how to get all commits which goes to new app release?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using hg flow (similar to git flow) approach.
I need all commits between my current branch "release/2.0.0" latest commit and previous "develop" commit in point there "release/1.0.0" was started.

In short words: I want all commits which will go in new release candidate package.
Please take a look at screenshot. 
I want all commits which are inside red line. They are all changes since previous app release.

[image]

Comment: The lower most feature branch also goes into your new release, so you likely want to include those, too - thus either your words need to change or the image ;).

Answer (score 4):

This is actually very easy with mercurial: [revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets) to the rescue!

You basically want to include everything which happend prior to your current dev release, but exclude that stuff which happend already prior to the last release:

```
hg log -r"ancestors(DEVREV) and not ancestors(RELEASE)"
```

where `DEVREV` is the revision of your current one and `RELEASE` the revision of the last release.

E.g.:

```
ingo@aeolus:~/hg-test$ hg log -G -T"{rev}: {desc}\n"
@  8: New release
|
| o  7: New dev stuff
| |
o |    6: Merge 4
|\ \
| | o  5: Add cc
| |/
| o  4: Add bb
| |
o |  3: Add d
| |
o |  2: Add c
| |
o |  1: Add b
|/
o  0: Add a

ingo@aeolus:~/hg-test$ hg log -r"ancestors(7) and not ancestors(8)"
changeset:   5:ce0558751c5a
user:        planetmaker <planetmaker@openttd.org>
date:        Wed Aug 22 16:14:12 2018 +0200
summary:     Add cc

changeset:   7:78f338d1c8fa
parent:      5:ce0558751c5a
user:        planetmaker <planetmaker@openttd.org>
date:        Tue Oct 09 13:02:20 2018 +0200
summary:     New dev stuff
```

You might want to try `--style=changelog` with the appropriate revset though.